# How to cpan install from a local source [Linux::Inotify2]

Tags: perl, cpan, inotify, cpanm

Trying to install Linux::Inotify on Fedora Core 6 x86 machine which ends up in failure.

Looks like the kernel which is below 2.6.36 doesn't support IN_EXCL_UNLINK. This causes the issue in installation. So I have modified the source code and tried to install. But cpan again replaces it with online repo.

```
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00_load.t ..... Undefined subroutine &Linux::Inotify2::IN_EXCL_UNLINK called at /root/.cpan/build/Linux-Inotify2-2.1/blib/lib/Linux/Inotify2.pm line 431.
Compilation failed in require at t/00_load.t line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/00_load.t line 3.
t/00_load.t ..... Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 1/1 subtests
t/01_inotify.t .. Undefined subroutine &Linux::Inotify2::IN_EXCL_UNLINK called at /root/.cpan/build/Linux-Inotify2-2.1/blib/lib/Linux/Inotify2.pm line 431.
Compilation failed in require at t/01_inotify.t line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/01_inotify.t line 2.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 before it could output anything.
t/01_inotify.t .. Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 5/5 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/00_load.t   (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 1 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
  Non-zero exit status: 255
t/01_inotify.t (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 5 tests but ran 0.
Files=2, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.01 usr  0.05 sys +  0.05 cusr  0.08 csys =  0.19 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/2 test programs. 1/1 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Is there a way to fix this one or install using CPAN local source?

Note: make install using source code is working fine after editing the source code.

Comment: Yes you could for example create a local patch that you apply to `Inotify2.pm` before you run `perl Makefile.PL`. Please also [notify the author](https://rt.cpan.org/Dist/Display.html?Name=Linux-Inotify2) of the module about this issue, maybe they will provide a fix in the future

Comment: "*make install using source code is working fine*" - then it is already installed.

Comment: Fedora Core 6 reached end of life in 2007! It hasn't had a security update in over a decade! Upgrade the OS as soon as possible!

Answer (score 4):

```sh
wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/ML/MLEHMANN/Linux-Inotify2-2.1.tar.gz
tar xzf Linux-Inotify2-2.1.tar.gz
cd Linux-Inotify2-2.1
...apply change...
perl Makefile.PL
make test
make install
```

It sounds like you've already done this, so you've already installed it. `cpan` won't replace it (if it sees the installed version (which it will, unless you used the wrong `perl`, or unless you used env var `PERL_MB_OPT` to tell ExtUtils::MakeMaker to install the module in a non-standard location and didn't tell CPAN via env var `PERL5LIB`)).

Comment: `cpanm --look Linux::Inotify2` also may be useful as the first steps here.

Answer (score 1):

> install using CPAN local source?

`cpanm` supports installing from a local tarball (containing the patched sources), see [synopsis](http://p3rl.org/cpanm#SYNOPSIS):

```
cpanm ~/dists/MyCompany-Enterprise-1.00.tar.gz   # install from a local file
```